# qemu/kvm: cannot connect multiple machines to the same socket

Tags: sockets, networking, port, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to simulate a little network of 3 machines using QEMU where a machine (deb1) is directly connected with the host and the other 2 machines (deb2, deb3):

```
                      Host 
                       |
           -----------deb1-----------
           |                        |
          deb2                     deb3
```

deb1 is connected to 2 different networks, one (vlan 1) connects deb1 with the host, on the other one (vlan 2) will connect deb1 with the two other machines, so deb1 must listen from the port 1234:

```
kvm -hda deb1.img -m 256 \
-net nic,vlan=1 -net user,vlan=1 -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:12:34:57 \
-net socket,vlan=2,listen=localhost:1234
```

deb2 and deb3 both must be connected to deb1, the only difference is their mac address:

deb2:

```
 kvm -hda deb2.img -m 256 -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:12:34:01 \
 -net socket,vlan=2,connect=localhost:1234
```

deb3:

```
 kvm -hda deb3.img -m 256 -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:12:34:02 \
 -net socket,vlan=2,connect=localhost:1234
```

Once the three machines are started I just set their ip address:

deb1:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.10.2
```

deb2:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.3
```

deb3:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.4
```

Here the problem:
the connection between `deb1` and `deb2` works perfectly,
but not the one between `deb1` and `deb3`. When I shutdown `deb2` then the connection between `deb1` and `deb3` start to works. It looks like `deb1` is not able to listen at the same time `deb2` and `deb3`.

What am I doing wrong?

I actually followed what is written in [this guide](http://www.h7.dion.ne.jp/~qemu-win/HowToNetwork-en.html#vlan.4) (look at the section 4.2 Guest-only network: "When you want to use more than three guest OSes, just connect to the one. Use different macaddr.")
and [this article](http://csortu.blogspot.fr/2009/12/building-virtual-network-with-qemu.html)

Answer (score 2):

`-net socket,{listen|connect}=...` is only suitable for 1:1 connections.

`netstat -anp46|grep qemu` shows that there is no connection between qemu of deb3 and deb1.

Use `-net socket,mcast=...` instead.